# Combine into one row with additional columns using CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I have a table for example let's call employment:

```
ID        NAME         Employer           StartDate          EndDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
20        John         Company A          2-5-2015           5-5-2018
20        John         Company B          5-10-2018          NULL
100       Bill         Company C          10-10-2017         10-15-2018
100       Bill         Company D          11-20-2018         3-5-2019
100       Bill         Company E          4-5-2019           NULL
```

What I am trying to do is build a report that has the following columns:

```
ID         NAME        Employer1      Employer2         Employer3
```

So for example, based on the table above, I'd like to show:

```
ID         NAME        Employer1      Employer2         Employer3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
20         John        Company B      Company A         NULL
100        Bill        Company E      Company D         Company C
```

I'd like for Employer1 column to always show their most recent/current employer, and descend from there for Employer2 and Employer3 column. If someone has only 1 employer, then the Employer2 and Employer3 should be NULL, and same if they have only 2 employers, then Employer3 should be NULL.

Comment: Why id = 50 for Bill in the results?

Comment: Apologies, that was my mistake, I've updated that now.

Comment: What if there are more than 3 rows for an id?

Comment: If there are more than 3, I'd like to take the top 3 with Employer1 being the most recent/current and descend to Employer2 and Employer3

Answer (score 4):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then employer end) Employer1,        
       max(case when rn = 2 then employer end) Employer2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then employer end) Employer3
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id, name order by startdate desc) rn
  from employment
) e
group by id, name
order by id, name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ded916da9fea0b85a9b8f28f6853e95).
Results:

```
>  id | name | Employer1 | Employer2 | Employer3
> --: | :--- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
>  20 | John | Company B | Company A | null     
> 100 | Bill | Company E | Company D | Company C
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work.  Conditional aggregation

```
;with emp_rn_cte as (
    select e.*, row_number() over (partition by e.ID order by e.StartDate) rn from Employment e)
select ID, [NAME],
       max(iif(er.rn=1, er.Employer, null)) Employer1,
       max(iif(er.rn=2, er.Employer, null)) Employer2,
       max(iif(er.rn=3, er.Employer, null)) Employer3
from
  emp_rn_cte er
where er.rn<=3
group by ID, [NAME]
order by ID, [NAME];
```